# Why am I getting a "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" error even when x is declared as a number in this function?

Tags: python

I am new to python and assigned with creating a simple function that converts temperature of one kind (C, F, K) to another. Simple enough, but when using x, default value set to 0, as an input in my function I am getting a "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" error. I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. my code and then the error is attached below.

```
import warnings

def convTemp(x=0, fro="C", to="F"):
if fro == "C" and to == "F":
    x = 1.8 * x + 32
    return x
elif fro == "C" and to == "K":
    x = x + 273.15
    return x
elif fro == "F" and to == "C":
    x = x * (5/9)-32
    return temp
elif fro == "F" and to == "K":
    x = (x * (5/9)-32)+273.15
    return x
elif fro == "K" and to == "C":
    x = x - 273.15
    return x
elif fro == "K" and to == "F":
    x = (9/5)*(x - 273.15) + 32
    return x
else:
    if fro == to:
        warnings.warn("Your 'fro' parameter is the same as your 'to' parameter!")



TypeError                                 Traceback (most 
recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e9e7ea7efd49> in <module>
      1 assert convTemp(0) == 32
----> 2 assert convTemp([0,10,20]) == [32, 50, 68]
      3 

<ipython-input-1-a8e50b49bfb6> in convTemp(x, fro, to)
      2 def convTemp(x=0, fro="C", to="F"):
      3     if fro == "C" and to == "F":
----> 4         x = 1.8 * x + 32
      5         return x
      6     elif fro == "C" and to == "K":

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I have attempted to fix this by declaring x to have a number value before the function and I have also tried explicitly listing x as an int, a float, and a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means you are trying to take a list or tuple and perform the multiply function using a non-integer value. For understanding, if you used an integer *n*, it would return that list *n* times.

For example `[0,1,2]*3` returns `[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]`.

Your function definition is:

```
def convTemp(x=0, fro="C", to="F"):
    if fro == "C" and to == "F":
        x = 1.8 * x + 32
        return x
...
```

You are calling your assert function with:

```
assert convTemp([0,10,20]) == [32, 50, 68]
```

What this is doing is adding the entire array into `x` within your function.

As noted above, `1.8 * [0,10,20]` cannot be performed.

Instead, you are looking to unpack each element in your array to your function call and return an output array. That is:

```
assert [convTemp(i) for i in [0,10,20]] == [32, 50, 68]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the code you have given, your code multiplies the argument `x` with numeric values. So, when you give it a float or integer value, it does arithmetic correctly. But when you give it a list, to multiply with a float, when it expects an integer, it gives an error. Because when you multiply a list with a integer, it will give you a list with all the items in the list *that integer* times, as pointed out by @slothrop in the comment section. Maybe you want something like:

```
def convTemp(x=0, fro="C", to="F"):
    if fro == "C" and to == "F":
        if isinstance(x, list): # isinstance() checks for the type of x
            converted_values = []
            for fro_temp in x:
                converted_temp = 1.8 * fro_temp + 32
                converted_values.append(converted_temp) # append() appends converted_temp to the end of the list
            return converted_values # return list with converted temps
        else:
            x = 1.8 * x + 32
            return x
```

Comment: *"It cannot multiply a list with numeric (float or integer)."* Lists can be multiplied by integers - for example `[5 6,7]*3` gives `[5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7]`. That wouldn't be useful here, but it's not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line passes, your second fails. This is because your function was designed for a single number, and not a list of numbers.

If the intention is to allow list of numbers, then keep the function signature that way `def convTemp(x=[0], fro='C', to='F')` and then build with that intention.

```
def convTemp(x=[0], fro='C', to='F'):
    return_x = []
    for measurement in x:
        <your logic here>
        return_x.append(<converted measurement>)
    ...
    return return_x
```

If you really require a function that takes both integer or list, then you need more logic to handle that - it's an odd design but can be done.

Comment: Ah thanks for spotting that. I've amended the response.